Flutter : do UI / widget logic in isolate
A particular UI involves building complex set of UI patterns including texts and other widgets inside the parent Container widget.
To simplify the usecase the requirement is to choose the child widget based on the space available after previously rendered widgets have been successfully rendered.
Eg:
Consider a row widget which can incrementally keep on adding widget if there is space available.

In this case the rectangle widget can no longer be added but the triangle can be.
Hence in order for this logic to work well:

Find the rendered size for all the children widgets
Based on the information available in #1 - determine which children widget could fit fine and which not.

The logic around this and the widget themselves can get complicated and can cause jank to the Main UI isolate. So the idea is to do the logical part in an Isolate. However as it seems for the documentation that the Isolates cannot have any UI or widget logic.
Is there any recommendation to do these complex UI based logics on an Isolate, get the necessary rendering and size information out for individual widget and then proceed?
Nutshell: How to do UI logics in an Isolate ?

"Nutshell: How to do UI logics in an Isolate ?" - documentation is right: you cannot do that

@Tejas Shrediwala, it's not possible to use UI logics in an Isolates.

Any way in which we are expose a part to atleast calculate what the rendering size of the widget would be!
